# How to write a SQL query in tabular formato

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I want to write a SQL query for the following:

1. |7|30|0|11|31
2. |07|30|00|11|13
3. |30|03
4. |30|68|71

I want the end result to be:

```
7
30
0
11
31
```

So far the code I have written eliminates `|` and concatenates all into one string.

SQL statement:

```
select replace(replace(replace(a_list,'|' ,' '),char(10),''),' ')
```

Result: 73001131

I have tried the answer given to my SQL query but it still doesn't work. Here is the screenshot for it:

[image]

Comment: HI . The result should be in a tabular format

Comment: SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(youcolumn, '|')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built int string_split (SQL2016 onwards I think) to do this. If you have an older version, search for SQL Server String Split functions and there are lots of examples out there.

```
declare @s varchar(50) = '|7|30|0|11|31'

SELECT * from string_split(@s, '|') where len(value)>0
```

Returns the following rows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to replace the bar with a new line return. This will accomplish it:

```
select replace(a_list, '|',CHAR(10)) as modified from my_data;
```

| modified |
| --- |
| 7 30 0 11 31 |

However, it creates an empty row in row 1 because all your values begin with a bar. Easy fix, where we ignore the first character with this:

```
select replace(right(a_list, len(a_list) - 1), '|', CHAR(10)) as modified
from my_data
```

| modified |
| --- |
| 7 30 0 11 31 |

Comment: Hi

It didnt work.

I am getting results in a column with space included. But i am not getting result in a tabular format. The desired result which i have mentioned above

The sql query 

select replace(@string, '|',char(13)) as modified 
go
select replace(right(@string, len(@string) - 1), '|', CHAR(10)) as modified

the sql query result for both sql query is

modified
7  30  0  11  31

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have a space, so how can you possibly be getting a space?

Comment: I's like to add screenshot but i am unable to

Comment: Hi . I have updated my question and have included the screenshot. Hope this helps in understanding the issue. I want to see the result in grid. not in text format. I can see the correct result  if i switch the query result to text. Also i have gone to options-->query results-->results to grid --> and ticked retain cr/lf on copy or save.(did some googling). However this hasnt helped either

Comment: So if you export the results as csv then I suspect you would also have the correct results. This to me just sounds like an issue with your query tool and how it's displayed. What are you using?

Comment: Hi. I am using SSMS 2016 and as mentioned above I have retained cr lf result to be stored when result is displayed front select statement